# Ubuntu nopcid boot option

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I'm doing a performance test for the Meltdown Patch.

I have a i5-8600K that supports both PCID & INVPCID, so if I have pti enabled on Ubuntu, it means PCID is enabled.

I checked the Ubuntu wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/SpectreAndMeltdown/MitigationControls

It says "Disable the PCID feature" - nopcid

This suggests that I can disable PCID while having pti = on

However, I have not really used linux much and do not know where I would need to specify this. Is this the way to do it properly? (https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter)

Thank you and sorry if I am breaching community guidelines.

Comment: Why _would_ you disable PCID but keep PTI? Isn't that going to ruin your performance even more?

Comment: @grawity I am trying to compare performance with and without PCID :P